# Primefaces Tree with checkbox, avoid check/uncheck when clicking anywhere on row

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

Primefaces offers http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/treeSelectionCheckbox.jsf

It's a good fit except the "click anywhere on row" behavior is not what I am looking for. I need other buttons and stuff on the row.

Answer (score 2):

You need to override the Primefaces Javascript for treeTable. Placing the following on on your page should disable this functionality for Primefaces 3.5:

```
PrimeFaces.widget.TreeTable.prototype.bindSelectionEvents = function() {
    var $this = this,
    rowSelector = this.jqId + ' .ui-treetable-data tr.ui-treetable-selectable-node';

    $(document).off('mouseover.treeTable mouseout.treeTable click.treeTable', rowSelector)
                .on('mouseover.treeTable', rowSelector, null, function(e) {
                    var element = $(this);
                    if(!element.hasClass('ui-state-highlight')) {
                        element.addClass('ui-state-hover');

                        if($this.isCheckboxSelection()) {
                            element.find('> td:first-child > div.ui-chkbox > div.ui-chkbox-box').addClass('ui-state-hover');
                        }
                    }
                })
                .on('mouseout.treeTable', rowSelector, null, function(e) {
                    var element = $(this);
                    if(!element.hasClass('ui-state-highlight')) {
                        element.removeClass('ui-state-hover');

                        if($this.isCheckboxSelection()) {
                            element.find('> td:first-child > div.ui-chkbox > div.ui-chkbox-box').removeClass('ui-state-hover');
                        }
                    }
                })
                .on('click.treeTable', rowSelector, null, function(e) {
                    // $this.onRowClick(e, $(this));  <-- commenting this out disables row selection
                    e.preventDefault();
                });

    if(this.isCheckboxSelection()) {
       var checkboxSelector = this.jqId + ' .ui-treetable-data tr.ui-treetable-selectable-node td:first-child div.ui-chkbox-box';
       $(document).off('click.treeTable', checkboxSelector)
                  .on('click.treeTable', checkboxSelector, null, function(e) {
                      var node = $(this).closest('tr.ui-treetable-selectable-node');
                      $this.toggleCheckboxNode(node);
                  });
    }
};
```

This will override the bindEvents() function of the TreeTable and disable selection when you click the row. Make sure you're overriding the javascript for the specific version of primefaces you're using.

Answer (score 0):

You can disable the selection through jQuery overriding the click event on tree-node-labels as follows:

```
jQuery(".ui-treenode-label").click(function(){
  return false;
});
```

Make sure to make that run every time the tree is rendered or updated via ajax.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your suggestion. It did not work for me.